# Как в golang повторно использовать набор функций для элементов разного типа?

Tags: golang

Есть структура (type ... struct), реализующая набор функций для работы с элементами определенного типа.
Нужно создать ещё несколько структур выполняющих точно такие же функции но с другим типом данных.
Цель - не дублировать код.

Пробовал на интерфейсах, описывающих только нужные для общих функций методы, реализуя их в каждом из типов элементов. При этом не понятно как вернуть исходный тип элемента после обработки общими функциями.
Пробовал вместо интерфейса элемента использовать interface{}. При этом тоже не вышло, к тому же нельзя переопределить общие методы, требующие конкретизации типа.

Возможно решение где-то в области наследования. Или в использовании какого-то другого подхода к такой задаче.

Пример кода:

```
package main

import "fmt"

// абстрактный элемент
type Element interface {
    GetID() string
    GetName() string
}

// конкретные элементы, реализующие интерфейсы абстрактного
type UserElement struct {
    ID        string
    FirstName string
    LastName  string
}

func (u *UserElement) GetID() string {
    return u.ID
}

func (u *UserElement) GetName() string {
    return u.FirstName
}

type DepartmentElement struct {
    ID   string
    Name string
    Code string
}

func (d *DepartmentElement) GetID() string {
    return d.ID
}

func (d *DepartmentElement) GetName() string {
    return d.Name
}

// абстрактное хранилище абстрактных элементов
type ElementsStore interface {
    Add(element Element)
    GetAll() []Element
}

type elementsStore struct {
    ElementsStore
    store []Element
}

func (s *elementsStore) add(element Element) {
    s.store = append(s.store, element)
}

func (s *elementsStore) GetAll() []Element {
    return s.store
}

// конкретные хранилища конкретных элментов, использующие методы абстрактного хранилища для работы со своими элементами
type UsersStore interface {
    ElementsStore
}

type usersStore struct {
    elementsStore
}

type DepartmentsStore interface {
    ElementsStore
}

type departmentsStore struct {
    elementsStore
}

// пример использования
func main() {
    // конкретные хранилища
    US := usersStore{}
    DS := departmentsStore{}

    // конкрентые объекты
    userEl := UserElement{ID: "u1", FirstName: "ufn1", LastName: "uln1"}
    depEl := DepartmentElement{ID: "f1", Name: "dn1"}

    // использование методов абстрактного хранилища
    US.add(&userEl)
    DS.add(&depEl)

    // возврат элементов методами абстрактного хранилища
    users := US.GetAll()
    for _, u := range users {
        fmt.Println(u.LastName) // @TODO - как получить обратно элемент типа UserElement?
    }

    departments := DS.GetAll()
    for _, d := range departments {
        fmt.Println(d.Name) // @TODO - как получить обратно элемент типа DepartmentElement?
    }
}
```

**upd**

добавил такое, как вариант решения:

```
func (s *usersStore) cast(element Element) *UserElement {
    el, ok := element.(*UserElement)
    if !ok {
        return nil
    }
    return el
}
func (s *departmentsStore) cast(element Element) *DepartmentElement {
    el, ok := element.(*DepartmentElement)
    if !ok {
        return nil
    }
    return el
}

...
// возврат элементов методами абстрактного хранилища
users := US.GetAll()
for _, u := range users {
    user := US.cast(u)
    if user != nil {
        fmt.Println(user.LastName)
    }
}

departments := DS.GetAll()
for _, d := range departments {
    dep := DS.cast(d)
    if dep != nil {
        fmt.Println(dep.Name)
    }
}
```

Comment: наверное тяжко после ООП)) рассмотрели вариант кастить в нужную вам структуру?

Comment: кастить? так?
`
users := US.GetAll()
    for _, u := range users {
        userEl := UserElement {
        ID: u.GetID(),
        FirstName: u.GetName(),
        LastName : u.GetLastName(), 
    }
`
пришлось бы абстрактному Element иметь все методы всех возможных его "наследников"

Comment: нашел, что такое кастить, и ниже ответили - `value, ok := u.(*UserElement)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно кастить в нужный вам тип. но это плохая идея. я бы порекомендовал вас не писать ElementsStore абстрактно. лучшей отойдите от парадигмы ООП. делайте проще(принцип KISS)

можно кастить в любую сущность(почти) в Go. Но это не очень безопасно, поэтому нужно проверять получилось ли кастить или нет. для этого и нужен `ok`. `ok` - это булевый тип данных, который указывает на успешность.

```
    // возврат элементов методами абстрактного хранилища
    users := US.GetAll()
    for _, u := range users {
        value, ok := u.(*UserElement)
        if ok {
            fmt.Println("this is UserElement")
            fmt.Println(value.LastName)
        } else {
            fmt.Println("this is not UserElement")
        }
    }

    departments := DS.GetAll()
    for _, d := range departments {
        value, ok := d.(*DepartmentElement)
        if ok {
            fmt.Println("this is DepartmentElement")
            fmt.Println(value.Name)
        } else {
            fmt.Println("this is not DepartmentElement")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Благодарю, только-что нашел аналогичный ответ здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24423099/16548587
Как можно решить задачу по другому (не ООП)? ElementsStore ведь нужен для реализации множества функций выполняющих одно и тоже, вместо их дублирования.